# Factory Girl self-join throwing validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to test a system for creating article translations where there is a self-join on the publications table.  I've created a factory that will create multiple translations and associate them with a 'parent' article.

Using Rails 5 with factory_girl 4.7.0, rspec, and Database_cleaner

All actions work as expected, but creating a test is the problem

Here's the relevant model validations and methods:

```
  # models/publication.rb

  has_many :translations, class_name: "Publication", foreign_key: "translation_id", dependent: :nullify
  belongs_to :translation, class_name: "Publication", optional: true

  validates :language, uniqueness: { scope: :translation_id }, if: :is_translation?

  def is_translation?
    !translation.nil?
  end
```

Factory (irrelevant code omitted):

```
  # spec/factories/publication.rb
  factory :publication, aliases: [:published_pub] do
    title 'Default Title'
    language 'EN'
    published

    after(:build) do |object|
      create(:version, publication: object)
    end

    #-- This is where I suspect the problem stems from

    trait :with_translations do
      association :user, factory: :random_user

      after(:build) do |object|
        create_list(:translation, 3, {user: object.user, translation:object})
      end
    end
  end

  factory :translation, class: Publication do
    sequence(:title) { |n| ['French Article', 'Spanish Article', 'German Article', 'Chinese Article'][n]}
    sequence(:language) { |n| ['FR', 'ES', 'DE', 'CN'][n]}
    user
  end
```

And a basic test:

```
    # spec/models/publication_spec.rb
    before(:each) do
      @translation_parent = create(:publication, :with_translations)
      @pub_without_trans = create(:publication, :with_random_user)
    end

    scenario 'is_translation?' do
      # No actual test code needed, this passes regardless
    end

    scenario 'has_translations?' do
      # No actual test code needed, this (and subsequent tests) fail regardless
    end
```

Finally, the error:

```
 Failure/Error: create_list(:translation, 3, {user: object.user, translation:object})

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Language has already been taken
```

The first test passes (and the publication object with translations is created correctly)but any subsequent test fails.  The issue is that I have a uniqueness validation scoped to translation_id and it appears that factorygirl is trying to add the generated translations to an already existing publication instead of creating an entirely new publication.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The issue was that the sequence iterator in the `translation` factory was not resetting to 0 after each test.  So after test 1, it started trying to access an array index that didn't exist. After it did that one more time, it triggered the validation and the tests failed!

The solution is not cute, but it's good enough for the time being

```
sequence(:language) do |iteration|
  array = ['FR', 'ES', 'DE', 'CN']
  # Returns a number between 0 and array.length
  array[iteration%array.length]
end
sequence(:title) do |iteration|
  array = ['French Article', 'Spanish Article', 'German Article', 'Chinese Article']
  # Returns a number between 0 and array.length
  array[iteration%array.length]
end
```